# Are there any alternatives to Mutt?

Tags: email, mutt, software-rec

I really like the idea of [Mutt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_(email_client)), reading mail in the terminal. I'm not really pleased with some inconsistencies and the IMAP handling. I set about trying to find some alternatives to Mutt, but I can't seem to find any.

What alternatives to the Mutt e-mail client exist for the Linux terminal?

Comment: I've seen a lot of folks using `gnus`, though haven't used it myself in a while.  BTW, what is it that you are struggling with?

Comment: Imap keeps hanging mutt because my internet can be a bit spotty. Keybindings are a bit inconsistent. I don't really like some of the spacing and placing of items. Haven't found a way yet to change the statusbar in the bottom.

Comment: Instead of mutt's native (and sub-par) IMAP handling, use OfflineIMAP to manage mail retrieval; that way you get excellent IMAP support and the most suckless MUA... If you want another MUA, look at notmuch.

Comment: I will look into offlineimap then first, thanks :)

Comment: --> http://www.courier-mta.org/cone/index.html

Comment: you can use the `mail` command, I fear you wont get happier with it.

Comment: @jaapz for the Status Bar: use `set status_chars` and `set status_format`. Check http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/the-homely-mutt/#configuring for an example.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris thanks for that link, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The obvious answer is [Alpine](http://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/), which used to be [Pine](http://www.washington.edu/pine/), but was freed by the University of Washington. Pine is non-free software, Alpine is free software. Alpine is quite similar to Mutt, but Mutt is generally considered to be more powerful and flexible. The current active branch of Alpine is a fork called Re-Alpine, since the University of Washington has largely ceased development of Alpine as of 2008.

The Wikipedia pages on [Pine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_(email_client)) and [Alpine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_(email_client)) cover the history adequately.

I'd recommend trying to figure out your issues with Mutt instead of jumping to another mail client. Alpine inherits a polished user interface from Pine, but has some significant limitations and inflexibilities compared to Mutt. Therefore, you may find using it comes with its own problems.

Personally, I've used Pine since 1994, and switched to Alpine when that became available. I've thought over the years that I ought to be using Mutt instead, but never managed a successful transition.

Incidentally, [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) was created by the late [Mark Crispin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Crispin), who used to work at the University of Washington developing IMAP. He was therefore also, unsurprisingly, responsible for Pine's IMAP support.

In the [Pine credits](https://web.archive.org/web/20181212133105/http://www.washington.edu/pine/overview/credits.html) he is listed thus:

```
C-Client library & IMAPd:       Mark Crispin
```

Comment: I will look into Re-alpine as well, thanks!

Comment: I'd like to echo Faheem Mitha's personal Pine story. Oddly, I switched from BSD `mail` to Pine around 1994.  I've tried `Mutt`, too, but never made the switch.

Comment: Also, because this is actually a legit answer to my question, I'll mark this as the accepted answer, although I've now wrestled a bit more with mutt to make it work to my liking :)

Answer (score 13):

Check these out:

- [sup](http://sup-heliotrope.github.io/) — A curses threads-with-tags style email client
- [aerc](https://aerc-mail.org/) — Asynchronous email client for your terminal
  (slow development)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to consider [`nmh`](http://www.nongnu.org/nmh), a set of programs for messing with mail. As each function is a separate command, you can mix and match, and combine them with any old Unix command/filter.

Never forget the venerable mail and Mail programs...

Answer (score 1):

[nmail](https://github.com/d99kris/nmail) is a terminal-based email client with a user interface similar to alpine. It's intended to be easy to set up and use. Disclosure: I'm the author of nmail.